# Google TV App to display MPEG2 streams from HDHomeRun Prime

Tags: android, udp, android-video-player, google-tv

I have been working on an app to allow me to get rid of my cable boxes and use a HDHomeRun Prime and GoogleTV boxes (Sony blu ray player current) with the newest 3.1 honeycomb update.  In preperation for the GTV Honeycomb update I  converted SiliconDust's libhdhomerun to java since GTV doesn't support the NDK. I can control the Prime through my app already.  I tested this by hardcoding the device target for the Prime to my laptop's IP and used VLC and opened the udp data steam ("udp://@:portNum").

I am stuck on how to get the udp datastream that is supposed to be sent to my GTV box to display in a VideoView in my application.  I believe I've tried using setVideoPath and setVideoURI and all I get is a popup about being unable to display the video.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports RTSP and HTTP only for use with `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView`. If you can figure out how to get an RTSP stream out of the HDHomeRun, use that `rtsp:` URL.

Google TV supports somewhat [more media formats](http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats.html) than does standard Android. If you can figure out how to get the HDHomeRun to serve up content in a supported format, use that.

You might also elect to contact the VLC folk and coordinate with them. They are working on an official VLC for Android port, and they may be interested in your assistance for getting their stuff working on a Google TV. Of course, I suspect they're heavily dependent upon the NDK, which may prove problematic.